# How to use php readfile code to open PDF file in new tab (wysiwyg)

Tags: php, pdf, wysiwyg, readfile, redactor.js

I'm using following code to open a PDF document from database. My problem is
the PDF document is opened in the current tab but I want it to open in a new tab instead.

```
$query = "SELECT name, type, size, content FROM files WHERE id = '$id'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);

header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$name");

echo $content;
```

I'm using `redactor wysiwyg` to add the PDF. Let me know if you need more info, thank you.

Comment: As far as I know you can't do this with PHP. You could open a new page with target="blank" and then direct that to the php script to open the PDF?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have solved my question, I'm a beginner so just forget what I commented last week. I have voted your comment because you did mentioned the solution to me, thank you.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem to open the PDF in new tab. We can't open new tab by using php code. Only can do it by adding the "target="_blank" in `redactor.js`

Following is part of the code from redactor WYSIWYG. You can found the "target="_blank" inside the code.

```
fileUploadCallback: function(json)
{
    var data = $.parseJSON(json);

    var text = $('#redactor_filename').val();
    if (text == '') text = data.filename;
    var link = '<a href="' + data.filelink + '" target="_blank">' + text + '</a>';

    // chrome fix
    if ($.browser.webkit && !!window.chrome) link = link + '&nbsp;'; 

    if ($.browser.msie) 
    {
        if (text != '') $(this.doc.getElementById('span' + this.spanid)).replaceWith(a);
    else $(this.doc.getElementById('span' + this.spanid)).after(link).remove();
        this.syncCode();
    }
    else this.execCommand('inserthtml', link);

    // file upload callback
    if (typeof this.opts.fileUploadCallback == 'function') 
    {
        this.opts.fileUploadCallback(this, data);
    }

    this.modalClose();
},
```

For more information, please get the code from [redactor WYSIWYG](https://imperavi.com/redactor/) website.